# Can features that are the same in every sample contribute to learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, lstm

For simplicity, let's say that I am monitoring 4 sensors for an ongoing metric.

The first column is the *sensor ID* and the second column is the *sensor type*.

```
[
  [
    [0, 0, 0.123],
    [1, 0, 0.456],
    [2, 1, 0.789],
    [3, 1, 0.555]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0.987],
    [1, 0, 0.654],
    [2, 1, 0.321],
    [3, 1, 0.666]     
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0.591],
    [1, 0, 0.824],
    [2, 1, 0.760],
    [3, 1, 0.888]      
  ]
]
```

If the first two columns are always the same values, will a CNN or an LSTM be able to learn from these columns or are they just redundant?

In my mind, the sensor ID could correspond with a postion on the map where different metrics are observed. Or the sensor type could correspond with some sort of sensitivity in the metric. But am I just kidding myself if they are the same in every sample?

I don't want to provide unnecessary dimensionality to the model.

Answer (score 0):

**It has no value if it is same for all the training set.**

Let's say, you are using a global health dataset for Life expectancy then country code can be a useful feature. It might contain hidden information.

But if you are doing the same analysis for one country e.g. India, keeping a feature country which has only one value *e.g. India*, will be of no use.

It will not show any variance, now the variance is shifted to States instead of Country compared to the last example.

In you data, I can see multiple Sensor Id. If very dataset will always have these 4 values and there is no explicit assumption for 3rd column which is dependent on 1st, you can remove the feature